# How to do version compatibility testing

Tags: manual-testing, api-testing

I have an App ver - 3.8 and minimum supported version is 4.0. If the App is older than 4.0, an update available is shown to the User within the App.
Is there a way to simulate or test this scenario

Comment: I might have missed the point... would you not just load v3.8 and see if the 'update available' message appears?

Comment: Is this some sort of client-server interaction?  You have api-testing as a tag.  Depending on the mechanism that the necessary level is found, mocking is probably an option.

Answer (score 1):

To test any thing is to simulate the conditions necessary to for the thing to happen and see if the thing happens.

To paraphrase what Dan Wilson said. If you want to see if v3.8 of an app prompts for an update, load v3.8 and see if it prompts for an update.

When you're working with multiple versions it helps to have a standard procedure for setting up the testing environment with with any supported version of your software.

Answer (score 0):

In any qa services, the terminology compatibility version testing is basically used for checking whether the features of app supports the latest version or not.

So, in order to test it below scenarios can be verified:

1. Generally if any user is using an old version build then a pop-up should be shown when user open the app using any older version. Verify that the latest version is mentioned in the app once update is complete.
2. Verify all the basic features of the app are fully functional: execution of smoke or sanity checklist can be done every time the version
3. Verify all the features that are added in latest build version (it is generally mentioned by developers in their release notes ) in order to make sure that all required changes are available in the latest build version.
4. Some of the apps have the feature of rolling back to previous build. If this feature is available in your app, then make sure to test this as well. In this scenario, basic test has to be done to make sure all latest changes are not shown again and user is able to move back to previous build anytime.